# Error in parsing backslash escape sequence in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON string obtained from an API:

```js
var inputString = '{ "AccountName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM"}'
console.log(JSON.parse(inputString)) // View in browser console to see real error
```

Above code gives error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 31
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at program.html:7

Now below code works:

```js
var inputString = '{ "AccountName": "NT AUTHORITY\\\\SYSTEM"}'
console.log(JSON.parse(inputString))
```

It shows the output:

```
{AccountName: "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"}
```

Backslash character is an escape sequence in JSON. But why do I require four backslashes to create a single backslash? Shouldn't it be only `\\`?

The JSON response that I'm getting from the API being called is giving me only two `\\` where ever there is a path. So my code is breaking. I believe API's JSON format is correct. When I  try to parse this response on online [JSON viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) then they are able to parse it successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the template literal is parsed. Just like in ordinary strings, a double backslash is translated into a single *literal* backslash. So, your initial `inputString`:

```
var inputString = `{ "AccountName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM"}`
```

will have a *single* backslash in it.

```js
console.log(`\\`.length);
```

Unlike plain Javascript strings (in which unnecessary backslashes are just ignored), JSON format *requires* that backslashes precede a special character to be escaped (like a `"` or another `\`). If a backslash and the following character *does not* translate to an escape character, a `SyntaxError` like the one you see in your question will be thrown.

So, to indicate a literal backslash in a JSON, you need two backslashes in the JSON, and to indicate a literal backslash in a Javascript string, you also need two backslashes. Together, you need four backslashes in order to indicate a literal backslash in the JSON.

If you wish to manually write strings that include *literal* backslashes, and you don't need to use escape characters, you might consider using `String.raw` for your template literals, which parse single backslashes as *literal backslashes* rather than as part of an escape sequence:

```js
console.log(
  String.raw`\\`.length
);
const inputString = String.raw`{ "AccountName": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM"}`;
console.log(JSON.parse(inputString))
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got string inside template string. One backslash is consumed by template string and the other is for quoted text