# JSON.parse failing if file path has \\u

Tags: javascript, json

From a REST API I am receiving a JSON string to which I am trying to parse using `JSON.parse()`, surprisingly it is failing if within a file path a folder name starts with character `u`.

For eg.

Consider below JSON:

`{"FullPath":"C:\\unitTest\\bcjmail-jdk15to18-1.70.jar"}`

This is a valid JSON, but I try to

`JSON.parse('{"FullPath":"C:\\unitTest\\bcjmail-jdk15to18-1.70.jar"}');`

Then it gives me error `JSON.parse: bad Unicode escape at line 1 column 18 of the JSON data` and if I modify the folder name `unitTest` to `aunitTest` then parsing is successful. Looks like if folder name is starting with character `u` then it is being considered as `\u` which is itself a escape character.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in parsing backslash escape sequence in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343137/error-in-parsing-backslash-escape-sequence-in-json)

Comment: Elie Asmar already said a pretty valid answer, I think it's the same case than this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807537/why-does-the-jquery-json-parser-need-double-escaping-for-backslashes

Comment: @lusc that question does not solve the problem. Because in my case backslash is already coming as escaped character, the issue only occurs when a string is starting with `\u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes are used as escape characters, and they need to be escaped themselves if they are to be included in the string.
You can also replace all backslashes with forward slashes and then  parse.

```
let jsonString = '{"FullPath":"C:/unitTest/bcjmail-jdk15to18-1.70.jar"}';
let obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(obj);  // { FullPath: 'C:/unitTest/bcjmail-jdk15to18-1.70.jar' }
```

OR

```
let jsonString = '{"FullPath":"C:\\\\unitTest\\\\bcjmail-jdk15to18-1.70.jar"}';
let obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(obj);  // { FullPath: 'C:\\unitTest\\bcjmail-jdk15to18-1.70.jar' }
```

Answer (score 0):

A JSON string must be double-quoted, according to the specs, so you don't need to escape '.
If you have to use special character in your JSON string, you can escape it using \ character.
So you can try this
`let s = '{"FullPath":"C:\\unitTest\\bcjmail-jdk15to18-1.70.jar"}' let sr = s.replaceAll('\\','/') JSON.parse(sr)`

Answer (score -1):

Try to stringify first

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"FullPath":"C:\\unitTest\\bcjmail-jdk15to18-1.70.jar"}))`